# CMake Include paths - library that depend on external library

Tags: c++, cmake

Take for example this project structure

```
project
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp
    libA
         src.cpp
         CMakeLists.txt
    libB
         foo.h
         foo.cpp
         CMakeLists.txt
```

**src.cpp** and **main.cpp**:

```
#include "foo.h"
.
.
.
```

I need both src.cpp and main.cpp to have libB in their include path, what I've tried to do is:

**libB/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(libB SHARED
    src.cpp)
```

**libA/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(libA SHARED
    foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libA libB)
```

project/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(libA)
add_subdirectory(libB)
add_executable(App main.cpp)
target_include_directories(App PUBLIC libB)
target_link_libraries(App libA libB)
```

And yet I get an error that
src.cpp: fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the top-level:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(project)

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libs instead of static" ON)

add_subdirectory(libA)
add_subdirectory(libB)

add_executable(App main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(App PRIVATE libA libB)
```

In libA:

```
add_library(libA src.cpp)

# Use PUBLIC below if libA exposes libB's types in its API.
target_link_libraries(libA PRIVATE libB)
```

In libB:

```
add_library(libB foo.cpp)
target_include_directories(
  libB PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>"
)
```

---

`PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` properties on targets *propagate* to their linkees. Thus, when we set up the include directories on `libB`, any target linking to it will get its source directory added it *its* include path.

We guard the include directory with `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>` so that if you ever `install()` the library somewhere it might be re-used in another CMake build, it won't remember details of your specific file system.

Comment: Why use target_include_directories(
  libB PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>"
)

instead of target_include_directories(
  libB PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}") ?

Comment: When you export a CMake target for other consumers, it saves all of its properties, too. `$<BUILD_INTERFACE>` prevents that for its content. If we didn't do this, then the exported target would have a path in it like `/home/alex/projects/lib/include`, which wouldn't be appropriate on someone else's machine.